# Stop() won't stop my video

Tags: jquery, css, video

I am trying to stop a video if there is a click detected inside the div. The removeClass works fine but I can hear the sound on the webpage. When I click the link again the video seem to be playing in the background. It doesn't stop and keep playing. How can I have fine control over my video responding to clicks?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".netball-intro").click(function() {
        jQuery(".fullscreen").addClass("is-video-active");
        jQuery("#netball-intro").get(0).play();

        jQuery(".fullscreen").click(function(){
            jQuery(this).removeClass("is-video-active");
            jQuery("#netball-intro").get(0).stop();
        });
    });
});
```

I am new to video element and i want my code to be dynamic so it can be reused for other videos as well. I am unable to do that also.

Comment: What is your HTML? If the `.fullscreen` element is inside the `.netball-intro` then the event may be bubbling and calling `play()` again.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my [codepen](http://codepen.io/codearts/pen/ggxexP)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried .pause() and it works but i am curious to know why .stop() won't work.It seem like it is not it the video API, and how can i make the code dynamic so i can use more videos with different ids and div.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you. Trying for Dynamic code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".netball-intro").click(function() {
        $(".fullscreen").addClass("is-video-active");
        $("#netball-intro").get(0).play();

        $(".fullscreen").click(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("is-video-active");
            $("#netball-intro").get(0).pause();
            $("#netball-intro").currentTime = 0;
        });    

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What does `currentTime` do? Also how can i make it more reusable as i got other videos on page which i think aren't same id and get(0)

Comment: Will working on dyanamic code and get back you shortly